# Send e-mail through VB.NET using SMTP

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

I really started to get confused about sending an e-mail to (example: test@test.com) through VB.NET and for sure using SMTP.

I want the mail to be sent when Button1 is clicked (example).

So I started by a code like that

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class MyProgram

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using message As New MailMessage()
            'set to the from, to and subject fields
            message.From = New MailAddress("sender@sender.com")
            message.[To].Add(New MailAddress("test@test.com"))
            message.Subject = "Test"
            'code the message body
            Dim MsgBody As String
            MsgBody = TextBox1.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                      TextBox2.Text.ToString()
            message.Body = MsgBody
            Dim client As New SmtpClient()
            client.Host = "smtp.example.com"
            client.Port = "465"
            client.EnableSsl = True
            client.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("USERNAME@MAIL.COM", "PASSWORD")
            client.Send(message)
        End Using
        'display submitted box
        MessageBox.Show("Congrats", "Congratulations!")
        'close form
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And I get:

[image]

Next, I tried another code (which is) ...

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class MyProgram

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
        Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
        Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("USERNAME@MAIL.COM", "PASSWORD")
        Smtp_Server.Port = 465
        Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
        Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.example.com"

        e_mail = New MailMessage()
        e_mail.From = New MailAddress("sender@sender.com")
        e_mail.To.Add("test@test.com")
        e_mail.Subject = "Test E-mail Address Sent by My Program"
        e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
        e_mail.Body = "Test"
        Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
        MsgBox("Mail Sent")
    End Sub
End Class
```

And now I get the following in the Debugger:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

And at last the e-mail isn't sent!

Please don't say "sender@sender.com" isn't configured as a sender e-mail address because it is!

I really need help!

Thanks. :-)

Comment: Looks like you application is blocked by something like a firewall for example to me. But I'm not sure about that - It's just a thought.

Comment: Are you sure the host and port are correct?

Comment: Is everything OK with the network? Can you ping the SMTP server?